# Laravel Eloquent relationship - strange paths

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models: `User` and `Form`. The `Form` model has two `belongsTo` relationships:

```
class Form extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function manager_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'manager_id');
    }
}
```

`manager_id` is a nullable integer column.

Using artisan tinker, I try to assign a user as a manager to a form (using [these methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)):

```
$manager = App\User::findOrFail(1);
$form = App\Form::findOrFail(1);
$form->manager_user()->assign($manager);
```

but I get error:

```
$form->manager_user()->associate($gacek)
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\App\User' not found in /var/www/html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 779                                                     

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Class 'App\App\User' not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the framework trying to search for `App\App\User` instead of `App\User`?

It's a fresh installation of Laravel 5.3.

**EDIT** 
Full model files with namespaces:

`Form` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Form extends Model
{
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
}

public function manager_user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'manager_id');
}
}
```

`User` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'surname', 'login', 'sign'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function forms(){
    return $this->hasMany(Form::class);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe namespace issue.

Comment: Can you show the namespace for your models!

Comment: Sure, see my edit.

Comment: Can you post the namespace for the file making the calls to the `App\{Class}::findOrFail()` entries as well?

Comment: There is no file - I do it in artisan tinker

Comment: Hmm; I spun up a new Laravel project and tried to replicate this, but this had worked. Just to toss out other possibilities, both files are located just within the app directory? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Both are in app directory, `User` was auto generated by make:auth command and Form was created by `make:model Form` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have a namespace resolution issue with the relative namespace class references `App\User` and `App\Form` with Laravel.

> By default, this directory is namespaced under App and is autoloaded by Composer using the PSR-4 autoloading standard. You may change this namespace using the app:name Artisan command.

[From Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/structure#the-app-directory)

> 2. Relative names always resolve to the name with namespace replaced by the current namespace. If the name occurs in the global namespace, the namespace\ prefix is stripped. For example namespace\A inside namespace X\Y resolves to X\Y\A. The same name inside the global namespace resolves to A.

From [Namespace Resolution rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)

Try either removing the `App\` namespace declaration before your `User` and `Form` class references or prefix them with another `\` to make them fully qualified.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. See also my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kevin Stitch suggested I had problem with relative namespaces.

In my `Form` model I adjusted the relationships to have absolute paths:

```
class Form extends Model
{
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("\App\User");
}

public function manager_user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("\App\User", 'manager_id');
}
}
```

And then everything works fine (after restarting the artisan tinker).